# Nginx how to redirect from https to http when not support https anymore

Tags: http, nginx

My site was https, and now I removed the certificates because I don't need https anymore. But I need a way to redirect my visitors to the HTTP version because maybe they have my domain bookmarked with the https version. 
I tried this:

```
server {
      listen 443;
      server_name example.com;
      ssl on;
      rewrite ^ http://$server_name$request_uri? permanent; 
}
```

But when I am trying to go to https://example.com it's stuck.
What am I doing wrong?

Comment: You cannot redirect from `https` to `http` without a server that supports `https`, and that includes the certificate.

Comment: So there is no solution to this problem without https support?

Comment: There are solutions available that use free certificates, but no solution without any certificate. Of course, if you go to the trouble of setting up a free certificate, why redirect? ;-)

Comment: You might want to consider the "I don't need https anymore" part. Google [ranks websites with https higher](https://security.googleblog.com/2014/08/https-as-ranking-signal_6.html). Also SSL certificates can be obtained freely nowadays through services like [letsencrypt](https://letsencrypt.org/). So, why not just keep supporting https?